# Graylog , Handle files before store it

Tags: bash, shell, rsyslog, graylog

I am trying to create log system using Gray log,
I have logs like this

```
Mon Aug 17 16:53:10 2020
        NAS-IP-Address = 172.20.101.1
        User-Name = "netconf"
        Acct-Status-Type = Start
        Acct-Session-Id = "ACCTID20200817112721000fe14d000000001040717"
        Acct-Authentic = RADIUS
        NAS-Identifier = "NR-DELHI-NRTCC-CR-01"
        Framed-IP-Address = 172.20.16.6
        NAS-Port-Type = Virtual
        Event-Timestamp = "Aug 17 2020 16:57:21 IST"
        Tmp-String-9 = "ai:"
        Acct-Unique-Session-Id = "23be63c276bbda95385d118ff93ba298"
        Timestamp = 1597663390

Mon Aug 17 16:54:15 2020
        NAS-IP-Address = 172.20.101.1
        User-Name = "netconf"
        Acct-Status-Type = Start
        Acct-Session-Id = "ACCTID20200817112825000fe14f000000001040719"
        Acct-Authentic = RADIUS
        NAS-Identifier = "NR-DELHI-NRTCC-CR-01"
        Framed-IP-Address = 172.20.16.6
        NAS-Port-Type = Virtual
        Event-Timestamp = "Aug 17 2020 16:58:25 IST"
        Tmp-String-9 = "ai:"
        Acct-Unique-Session-Id = "49fcad388a523e7eebea6043529c323e"
        Timestamp = 1597663455
```

actually, every block is one log record, but the problem is that Graylog considering every line as a separated log, so what I want is to tell Graylog to read every block as one record.
is there any way to do that, some configuration that I have to do in Gray log to achieve my goal.
I have an idea but I am not sure about it, I am thinking about creating a bash script which will read the file and merge lines which belong to one block in one line,
but I am not sure if this method will work or not, so I am wondering if there is any way to do it from Graylog itself.
any suggestion will be appreciate
Best Regards

Comment: Can you provide details about how do you ship the logs to Graylog ?

Answer (score 0):

if messages in the log file begin with a blank line, then you could use the `readmode` parameter of the `imfile` module: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html#readmode